# socks server with "dynamic traffic routing" trought Tor / I2P depending on the extension .i2p .onion

Tags: security, socks, i2p

To browse the web, I connect to ssh and make a tunnel to an http proxy (privoxy) who is configured to "route" the traffic depending on the extension, here is an extract of the privoxy config file :

`forward .i2p localhost:4444

forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .`

basically, if the domain ends with ".i2p" it forwards the traffic to i2p and forward it to tor otherwise.

So in Firefox I configure an http proxy (through a local port forwarding) BUT in these case it seems that I have a DNS leak and there is no obvious solution, so my question is:

If I configure firefox with a socks proxy instead of an http proxy how can I write flexible rules to "route" the traffic to i2p, Tor, or eventually direct traffic (like my previous privoxy config)?

Comment: What makes you think you have a DNS leak? Knowing the symptoms might help identify/solve the problem.

Comment: If you give a relatively recent version of Firefox a SOCKS proxy, it should use that for lookups and connections.

Comment: Because I used an HTTP proxy to "route" traffic to tor/i2p and I would like to do that with a socks proxy because as far as I know, an HTTP Proxy is not capable of forwarding DNS queries (whereas a socks proxy can !). am I wrong ?

Comment: @flamsmark yeah I know, I have to use socks proxy instead of HTTP proxy, but then, how could I route traffic to tor/i2p depending on the extension (like I does in my privoxy config)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a socks server with a routing feature, you could always use some intelligent proxy selection in firefox itself.

Using the [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) addon, you can say "Use proxy  for URLs matching http://*.i2p.; use proxy  for everything else".

[Ceterum censeo: using normal Firefox instead of the [TBB](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) is probably not very safe.]